# How to get the location ids of nearby places in a FB app?

Tags: facebook, geolocation, facebook-apps

I'm creating a Facebook app in which I want to display content depending on the location of the user.
Realtime geolocation is not needed, but I would like to use the user's location id provided by Facebook. So what I need is a function that takes the user's location id and a given radius as input parameters and returns the location ids of towns, villages within the radius.

I saw that Facebook's area based lists use such methods to filter friends. But I have no idea how to implement it in my own application. Any hints? Tutorials? Sample codes? I'd be grateful if you could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using the location ID get the coordinates of the respective page
2) Call the graph API's search for locations (see Search section of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) using those coordinates.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

or

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000